# How can I concurrently load a single webpage in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency

I'm using

```
    html = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

to load the html from a webpage.  However, it takes 10-15 seconds usually (on the wifi at Starbucks).  It seems like the task wouldn't lend itself to parallelization because only one page is being loaded.  But I was wondering if I could have many threads each load part of the HTML and then join the strings together.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the task *wouldn't lend itself to parallelization because only one page is being loaded*, but you sure as hell don't want to do the load on the UI thread!

To keep your UI responsive, you will want to do the load on a background thread then post the result back to the UI thread when it is complete. This is what the `-[UIWebView loadRequest:]` will be doing internally. This way you can display a progress spinner while the page is loading, or allow the user to press back to cancel the load.

There are numerous ways to run a task on a background thread in iOS. Probably the easiest way here is to use `dispatch_async()` and do the load inside a block. Or for more control (e.g. to allow cancelling) use an `NSOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UIWebView`'s `loadRequest:` method is already asynchronous. From the docs:

> Connects to a given URL by initiating an asynchronous client request.

So all you have to do is use this method, and your UI will remain responsive during the load - even at Starbucks ;-).

Comment: Well I need to actually get the HTML as a string so I can process it using a regular expression.  At least the way I'm doing it now.  Thanks for the tip though!